# Copy Table to Excel via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I have used some example code I got off here:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/03/08/get-data-from-website-that-requires-a-login/

But it is quite old and the website I am trying to get the table from has it under:

```
<table class="list">
```

Rather than the way the table is set up on the example website, I want to copy the whole table in

```
<table class="list">
```

Is there any way to modify that code as I still need to login, once logged in the table is visble.

Thanks for any help guys, hopefully this is any easy one.

Answer (score 1):

The website example finds the table by:

```
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("sampletable")
```

In essence it is manipulaing the DOM (Document Object Model) of the HTML page. You need to modify this to get your table.

If there is only ONE table on your webpage, then probably the following will work:

```
    Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
```

or:

```
    Set ieTable = ieDoc.body.all.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
```

`getElementsByTagName()` is the DOM method to get an element from the webpage by its tag name. The tag name is "TABLE". As this method returns a collection, it might still be necessary to get an element from the collection, which you can do by:

```
    Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0]
```

to get the first element.

For more information, see the DOM documentation (just google for "DOM documentation").